# Single-machine install and capabilites

Tags: web8, installation, discovery-service

Running through the [single-machine installation for 8.5](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88) and have come across a lot of problems that I think are due to missing capabilities registered with my Discovery service.

Can I check that as part of the instructions you're installing the following services:

- Deployer
- Discovery
- Session-Enabled
- Preview

So in the cd_storage_conf of my Discovery service I need to Deployer, Session-Enabled and Preview capabilities within the  and registered using discovery-registration.jar.

Is that right?
Should the quickinstall have done all that for me?

Comment: There is a missing parameter in the docs: -auto-register.  https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/blob/master/Web-8.5-Quick-Install.ps1#L341

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrrrrrr!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `quickinstall.ps1` powershell script for CD installation, then use the `-auto-register` switch as mentioned by Nuno.

In case you have done the installation without this switch, then compare the cd_storage_config.xml for Discovery service from the Installation media (`\Content Delivery\roles\discovery\standalone\config`) with the one available in the installed discovery service (defaulted to `C:\SDL\Web\discovery\config`) and add the missing `Roles`in it - In my scenario it was missing the `WebCapability` role only while the `TokenServiceCapability` was available in the config file.

Once you have updated the config file, copy the `discovery-registration.jar` file from the Install Package -`\Content Delivery\roles\discovery\registration`  to the corresponding location at the installed instance of Discovery Service. Execute the following command to register these capabilities: `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update`

Comment: The web capability missing is the harder to fix - basically you need to add it to storage Conf yourself. To fix the -auto-register switch missing just run quick-install again, but add the switch. The script will reinstall the services with the new parameters

Comment: I may be missing something, but I just compare the cd_Storage_config from the installer package with the one in the discovery service install - and just copy pasted the Web Capability roles as it is from their follower by discovery service registration

Comment: Am I right in thinking that its not the case that the Discovery service should have all capabilities listed in its storage file - each role should auto-register with the Discovery database as its installed. I think I was expecting the Discovery services storage file to have all the capabilities defined within it.

Comment: Why is it during installation of these services I always see "WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:xxx failed" ???

Comment: If a service auto-registers, it will not show in the Conf, only if you query the service. The warnings are because the scripts are waiting for the service to respond, but while installing it takes a few seconds (maybe up to 40-50 seconds) until the services are up & running.